# so I have a gif and want to make it so that continuously plays while I hold down a key to move how can I do that in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a gif and want to make it so that continuously plays while I hold down a key to move how can I do that in JavaScript/jQuery?

this is what I have now:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $( document ).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        // Left arrow key pressed
        case 37:

            $('img').animate({left: "-=50px"}, 'fast');
                            $('img').attr('src','http://i.imgur.com/IvR83ue.gif');
            break;
```

Comment: can you please add your html code?

Comment: my html is only an image tag.

Comment: try the keypress event instead. It is continuous. Also, unbind the key event on the start of each animation then rebind it at the end so you dont crash the browser.